# How do I retrieve a video ID or URL from YouTube, if I pass an artist or song name?

Tags: ios, youtube

How do I retrieve a video ID or URL from YouTube, if I pass an artist or song name from my iOS app?

Comment: There is a nice tutorial [here](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/how-to-make-a-youtube-app-using-mgbox-and-jsonmodel/) to do what you want to in your app. Download there sample project from [Github](https://github.com/JSONModel/YouTubeBrowserDemo).

Answer (score 1):

Check out YouTube's GData API.  Specifically their search feeds: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters#Searching_for_Videos